# I created a password generator in javascript, but it's giving an error and I can't see it

Tags: javascript

I can't execute the aleatory password on HTML, but I don't see anything of the problem...

**CODE:**

`function generator() {

```
const passwordCode = "1234567890hanshcnmasiuqyeue&*¨%$#@naihd=-"

const sizeTxt = 12;
const fieldCode = "";

for(var i = 0; i<sizeTxt; i++){
    var randomCode_Generator = Math.floor(Math.random() * passwordCode.length);

    fieldCode += passwordCode.substring(randomCode_Generator, randomCode_Generator * 25);
    
}
document.getElementById('txt_code').value = fieldCode;
```

}
`

**HTML**
`

```
            <script src="passwordCode.js"></script>
            
            
        </header>
    </main>

</body>
```

`

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're assigning to a constant, which cannot be assigned after its initialized.
The fix for it was modifying `const fieldCode = "";` to `let fieldCode = "";`

```
const passwordCode = "1234567890hanshcnmasiuqyeue&*¨%$#@naihd=-"
const sizeTxt = 12;
let fieldCode = ""; // here's your fix
```